# Questions Regarding Icons on PageSpeed Insights

Tags: icons, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have a question regarding PageSpeed Insights' icons.

There are some opportunities that are labelled with red and orange icons, while diagnostics are labelled with a red icon, orange icon and grey icon.

See screenshot of the icons I am referring to: [PageSpeed Insight Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycoRN.png)

I have done checks online and it seems that they represent the level of importance for fixing the issue (red icons are the most important, followed by the orange icon and then the grey icons)

Could someone confirm whether my research and inference is correct? Otherwise, I would appreciate clarifications on the correct definition. Thank you!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Resolving the issues listed in red and orange will give maximum boost in term of pagespeed score since those issues are the one affecting the most for the concerned site.